# MySQL Sort by Month in PHP script

Tags: php, mysql

Trying to get my results sorted by month and displayed in a table. Where am I going wrong?

Query:

```
mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*), DATE_FORMAT(DATE(`dPostDateTime`), '%W, %b, %e') AS `day`, DATE(`dPostDateTime`) AS 'date' FROM `tblQA` WHERE cCategory IN ('Football','Baseball','Basketball','Hockey') AND dPostDateTime >= '2010-08-01' AND dPostDateTime <= '2011-07-31' GROUP BY `month`");
```

PHP Code:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($monthlyQ))
{
$printedRecords1++;
echo "<tr class='forum'>";
echo "<td class='forum'>" . $row['month'] . "</td>";
echo "<td class='forum'>" . $row['COUNT(*)'] . "</td>";
echo "</tr>";
}
for ($i = $printedRecords1; $i < $Print; $i++) {
echo "<tr class='forum'>"; 
echo "<td class='forum'>&nbsp;</td>";
echo "<td class='forum'>&nbsp;</td>";
echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table></td><td>";
```

Comment: why not order by month in the query itself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume when you say you're trying to sort by month, you just mean you're trying to figure out how many rows are in each month, since that looks what what your code is doing.

If you actually have a 'month' field in your table, then your SQL is fine, except that you never actually select that field, so `$row['month']` shouldn't have a value with that SQL.
So you need to select it like below:

```
mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*), `month`, DATE_FORMAT(DATE(`dPostDateTime`), '%W, %b, %e') AS `day`, DATE(`dPostDateTime`) AS 'date' FROM `tblQA` WHERE cCategory IN ('Football','Baseball','Basketball','Hockey') AND dPostDateTime >= '2010-08-01' AND dPostDateTime <= '2011-07-31' GROUP BY `month`");
```

If you don't have a 'month' field (and just have the date field, which would mean your query as given shouldn't be working) you need to be creating that in a similar way as your 'day'.

```
mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*), MONTH(`dPostDateTime`) AS `month`, DATE_FORMAT(DATE(`dPostDateTime`), '%W, %b, %e') AS `day`, DATE(`dPostDateTime`) AS 'date' FROM `tblQA` WHERE cCategory IN ('Football','Baseball','Basketball','Hockey') AND dPostDateTime >= '2010-08-01' AND dPostDateTime <= '2011-07-31' GROUP BY `month`");
```

Then, if you want your results to be ordered by the month as well, so the table goes in a cronological order, you'd want to add `ORDER BY month` in there as well, assuming it exists (as in example 1) or you're creating it (as in example 2).

Comment: how can I order by month if I use MONTHNAME instead?

Comment: You can really just `ORDER BY dPostDataTime`, it's just going to order all your rows, since you're then just grouping by month it doesn't matter.  Probably the easiest solution that will just work no matter what.

Answer (score 0):

If you want them sorted by month, then you need to add

```
ORDER BY `month`
```

to your SQL

Comment: more like `ORDER BY MONTH(dPostDateTime)` - there's no month field in the query sample.

Comment: @Marc B: You're probably right. There's a `GROUP BY month`, and a `$month` variable that threw me.